# Height of div after appending elements via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I do an ajax call to retrieve some json and this data is appended to div #example, and I want to obtain the height of the #example using $('#example').height(). If I obtain the height right away, all the items may not be appended yet. I am trying to obtain the height within the success clause of the ajax call at the end after the appending loops, but the appending action must not be completed yet because I keep getting a smaller height than expected. What is the most favorable course of action to have accurate timing in obtaining the height of #example?

Comment: Please show your code and your output / expected output

Comment: if the height is called after appending the elements, it should work fine, unless the height is dependent some images that are yet to be loaded? also, could it be because you'd want outerHeight() since height doesn't account for padding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try obtaining the height on success of the ajax call?

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/example',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#example').height();
  },
  complete: function(data) {
    $('#example').height();
  }
});
```

If that still doesn't work, try using a setTimeout for 500 miliseconds to makes sure $('#example') has been populated. I've also heard of "complete" param for ajax.

Comment: why 500? and not 600?

Comment: It's just random really. @paulalexandru is right, you may only need 200-300 ms. From experience, 500ms is long enough time for the browser to process, but short enough so that users can't detect any real delay. Makes sense?